# Get notified when a Window closes (or it's owning thread disappears)

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a hwnd, which my process does not own, and I want to be notified when it disappears so that my code can perform cleanup actions.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: For the most part, you don't. What is your scenario?

Comment: I have a process which creates a child window of another process' window - I need to know if the user alt+f4 or somehow kills that process, making my parent window go away without firing the standard messages

Comment: @Ben: You're reaching into another process and creating windows under it? Yikes!

Comment: Maybe, just maybe you can subclass the window and listen to `WM_NCDESTROY`. Not sure if you can subclass other processes windows though.

Comment: No, you cannot subclass windows across thread boundaries, let alone process boundaries.

Comment: If your window is a child of the other window, then your child should get the usual destruction messages (e.g., WM_DESTROY) as the parent window is being destroyed.  These messares are the cue to clean up.  Note, however, that this is a tricky think, as you've effectively tied your thread input queue to the other process's thread input queue, so if either one messes up, you're both in trouble.

Comment: Use SetWinEventHook().

Comment: Is the other process's window a top-level window?  Or is it a child or owned window of yet another one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect when the HWND's owning process disappears, you can get the HWND's process ID from `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`, then get a `HANDLE` to the process using `OpenProcess()`, and then use `WaitForSingleObject()` or other related wait function.  A process handle is signaled when the process exits.

To detect when just the HWND disappears, get the HWND's thread ID from `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` and then use `SetWindowsHookEx()` to hook the message queue of that thread so you can intercept `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_NCDESTROY` messages for all HWNDs belonging to that thread, looking for the particular HWND that you are interested in.  Note that your hook must be implemented in a DLL when hooking another process, so you will have to use an inter-process communication mechanism of your choosing to notify your main app when the HWND is destroyed.

Comment: The first is the solution I came up with as well. I was just hoping for some more Window specific. The hook system is OK for that, but I've decided to just go with the first solution until I can see a case it doesn't cover. Thanks.